# MVC ASP .NET - Generating PDF file

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pdf-generation, itext

I have an C# application in MVC 4 and ASP.NET.

What I want to do, is to push a button in my razor view, that sends the model to a controller. Here I want to create a pdf-file and return it to the view. The user can then save or open the pdf in his browser. I do NOT want to save the file on the server, memory only.

I have tried google to find examples of this. Something that come up a lot is iTextSharp. But I can't find any good examples of code that show exactly what I need.

The pdf will be created of data from the model.
I will need to change fonts and size of fonts + place these exactly where I want in the pdf-file. I will also need to place some photos (logo) at the top or bottom.

There will also be a button that sends the file to this persons email. Would be great if I could re-use some code for that.

Does anyone have any libraries or examples of how to do this?

In advance thanx.

EDIT:
After a lot of googling, i found an example that I could strip down to something I can use. I have only tried it with a single line of text, but I think I can build on it to get what I need. I am at least able to change fonts. Now I must see if I can place the content exactly where I want.
here is the code to create a file the user can save on his device:

```
    public ActionResult CreatePdf()
    {
        MemoryStream workStream = new MemoryStream();
        Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4);
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, workStream).CloseStream = false;
        doc.Open();

        Paragraph p = new Paragraph("This is a text in my file");

        doc.Add(p);
        doc.Close();

        byte[] byteInfo = workStream.ToArray();
        workStream.Write(byteInfo, 0, byteInfo.Length);
        workStream.Position = 0;

        return File(byteInfo, "application/pdf", "file.pdf");
    }
```

Comment: Can you check this quick article - http://www.intstrings.com/ramivemula/articles/export-asp-net-mvc-view-to-pdf-in-3-quick-steps/. Let me know if it helps. I can do a simple POC and paste it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am not clear on what you want to achieve actually but what I have done is to use tables to have formatting and add content in the cells accordingly. If table was not to be visible then I hid the border. You can find a tutorial on this here: http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/86/itextsharp-introducing-tables

Answer (score 0):

I thought your requirement is with button click you want to return PDF (Create / Open  PDF file with out saving in the server) with different fonts,own styles and need to define logos .[enter image description here][1]
    If you want to define logo use logo block.

```
    The best solution is using iTextSharp pdf tools.Its a free tool.
    1)First initialize nuget packages.
     itextsharp and itextsharp.xmlworker.
    2)Define namespaces 
    using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
    using iTextSharp.text;
    using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
    3)Start creating PDF file coding.
     public ActionResult GetEmployeeListPDF()
            {
                MemoryStream workStream = new MemoryStream();
                //file name to be created   
                string PDFFileName = string.Format("EmployesList.pdf");
                Document doc = new Document();
                //Create PDF Table with 4 columns  
                PdfPTable tableLayout = new PdfPTable(4);
                //Create PDF Table  
                //file will created in this path  
                PdfWriter writerms = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, workStream);
                writerms.CloseStream = false;
                doc.Open();
                //We have option to assign titles logos /images any thing
                BaseFont f_cb = BaseFont.CreateFont("c:\\windows\\fonts\\calibrib.ttf", BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
                PdfContentByte cb = writerms.DirectContent;
                cb.BeginText();
                cb.SetFontAndSize(f_cb, 16);
                string text = "XYZ PVT. LTD";
                cb.ShowTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_CENTER, text, 280, 770, 0);
                cb.EndText();
                cb.SetLineWidth(0.5f);   // Make a bit thicker than 1.0 default
                cb.MoveTo(0, 755);
                cb.LineTo(750, 755);
                cb.SetRGBColorStroke(0, 0, 0);
                cb.Stroke();
                //Here if we want to define logo ,use this block
                //var logoPath = Server.MapPath("~/logo.jpg");
                //iTextSharp.text.Image png = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(logoPath);
                //png.SetAbsolutePosition(150, 950);
                //png.ScaleAbsolute(250, 70);
                //png.PaddingTop = 0;
                //doc.Add(png);
                //Add Content to PDF   
                doc.Add(Add_Content_To_PDF(tableLayout));
                // Closing the document  
                doc.Close();
                byte[] byteInfo = workStream.ToArray();
                workStream.Write(byteInfo, 0, byteInfo.Length);
                workStream.Position = 0;
                return File(workStream, "application/pdf", PDFFileName);
            }
            protected PdfPTable Add_Content_To_PDF(PdfPTable tableLayout)
            {
                float[] headers = { 30, 30, 30, 15 }; //Header Widths  
                tableLayout.SetWidths(headers); //Set the pdf headers  
                tableLayout.WidthPercentage = 100; //Set the PDF File witdh percentage  
                //Add Title to the PDF file at the top
                tableLayout.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase(" ", new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 10, 1, new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(153, 51, 0)))) { Colspan = 6, Border = 0, PaddingBottom = 0, PaddingTop = 45, HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER });
                ////Add header  
                //tableLayout.SpacingBefore = 250f;
                //If you want add any spaces ,margings or padding any styles before header you can add here.
                //AddCellHeader function defining for common styles we written methos other wise you candefine heades directly here it self like
                AddCellToHeader(tableLayout, "Name");
                AddCellToHeader(tableLayout, "Phone No");
                AddCellToHeader(tableLayout, "Gender");
                AddCellToHeader(tableLayout, "Sal");

                var date = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
                ////Add body  
                //List<EmployeeList> EmployeeList = GetEmployeeList();Fetch list of employees from database then pass that list in layout body.
                //foreach (var emp in EmployeeList)
                //{
                //    AddCellToBody(tableLayout, emp.Name);
                //    AddCellToBody(tableLayout, emp.Phone);
                //    AddCellToBody(tableLayout, emp.Gender);
                //    AddCellToBody(tableLayout, emp.Sal);
                //}
                //Just for understanding I AMBModular hardcoding 
                AddCellToBody(tableLayout,"ABC");
                AddCellToBody(tableLayout, "9999999999");
                AddCellToBody(tableLayout, "Male");
                AddCellToBody(tableLayout, "20000");
                AddCellToBody(tableLayout, "def");
                AddCellToBody(tableLayout, "9999999999");
                AddCellToBody(tableLayout, "Male");
                AddCellToBody(tableLayout, "35000");
                AddCellToBody(tableLayout, "xys");
                AddCellToBody(tableLayout, "9999999999");
                AddCellToBody(tableLayout, "Female");
                AddCellToBody(tableLayout, "50000");
                tableLayout.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Total Sal Amount", new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 7, 1, iTextSharp.text.BaseColor.BLACK))) { HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER, Padding = 3, BackgroundColor = new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(211, 211, 211),Colspan=3 });
                tableLayout.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("1,05,000", new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 7, 1, iTextSharp.text.BaseColor.BLACK))) { HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER, Padding = 3, BackgroundColor = new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(211, 211, 211) });
                return tableLayout;
            }

            // Method to add single cell to the Header  
            private static void AddCellToHeader(PdfPTable tableLayout, string cellText)
            {
                tableLayout.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase(cellText, new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 7, 1, iTextSharp.text.BaseColor.BLACK))) { HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER, Padding = 3, BackgroundColor = new iTextSharp.text.BaseColor(211, 211, 211) });//if you want to define any colspan to our table.we need to write same methos with different name and define colspan or row span anything.
            }
            // Method to add single cell to the body  
            private static void AddCellToBody(PdfPTable tableLayout, string cellText)
            {
                tableLayout.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase(cellText, new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 7, 1, iTextSharp.text.BaseColor.BLACK))) { HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER, Padding = 3, BackgroundColor = iTextSharp.text.BaseColor.WHITE });//if you want to define any colspan to our table.we need to write same methos with different name and define colspan or row span anything.
            }



  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Io2lO.jpg
```